# Could Microsoft speech recognition api recognize all English words just like google api?

Tags: speech-recognition

Using Microsoft's speech recognition API, I must define the grammar using the code like this:

```
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("test")));
```

And the engine could only recognize it's "test" or not.

But the Google speech recognition API could recognize nearly all English words. For example, in their demo page https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html, you could say whatever you want.

I wonder could the Microsoft API do the same thing? Or could I program using Google API in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DictationGrammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar(v=vs.110).aspx), then it will recognize freeform text